# Using variable argument can't print proper integers

Tags: c

Need some help in printing correct values of integer using custom print function.  This is my code — what's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void prints(int n, ...)
{
    int i=0;
    va_list argument;
    va_start(argument, n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d", va_arg(argument, int));
    }
    va_end(argument);
}

int main()
{
    prints(5);
    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way you call your function:

```
prints(5);
```

You tell the function you're going to provide 5 integers as arguments, but omit all those integers. It's no surprise that you get funny results. Use something like this, which provides 5 integer arguments:

```
prints(5, 0, -37, 248, 1239121, -91124887);
```

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static
void prints(int n, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", va_arg(args, int));
    }
    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    prints(5, 0, -37, 248, 1239121, -91124887);
    putchar('\n');
    prints(3, 99, 100, 101);
    putchar('\n');
    prints(1, 3141592);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
-37
248
1239121
-91124887

99
100
101

3141592
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jonathan, yes I put only one argument.